error: ./main.go:89:17: sql.Open undefined (type string has no field or method Open) during the go build main.go
Intent: I am picking a "alter_statements.sql" existing file, which has all the "ALTER TABLE..." statements.
Code:
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

// Define your SQL file path
const sqlFilePath = "alter_statements.sql"

// Define checkpoint file path
const checkpointFilePath = "checkpoint.txt"

// Define your database configurations
var dbConfigs = []map[string]string{
    {
        "host":     "xxxx",
        "port":     "5432",
        "database": "xxxx",
        "user":     "xxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxxxxx",
    },
}

// Function to execute SQL statements
func executeSQL(db *sql.DB, sql string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    _, err := db.Exec(sql)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error executing SQL: %s", err)
        return
    }

    log.Printf("SQL executed successfully")
}

// Function to read checkpoint
func readCheckpoint() (int, error) {
    if _, err := os.Stat(checkpointFilePath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return 0, nil
    }

    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(checkpointFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    var checkpoint int
    _, err = fmt.Sscanf(string(content), "%d", &checkpoint)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    return checkpoint, nil
}

// Function to write checkpoint
func writeCheckpoint(count int) error {
    return ioutil.WriteFile(checkpointFilePath, []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d", count)), 0644)
}

func main() {
    // Read SQL file
    sqlBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(sqlFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error reading SQL file: %s", err)
    }
    sql := string(sqlBytes)

    // Read checkpoint
    checkpoint, err := readCheckpoint()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error reading checkpoint: %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Resuming migration from checkpoint: %d", checkpoint)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Connect to the database
    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s dbname=%s user=%s password=%s sslmode=disable",
        dbConfigs[0]["host"], dbConfigs[0]["port"], dbConfigs[0]["database"], dbConfigs[0]["user"], dbConfigs[0]["password"])
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error connecting to database: %s", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Execute SQL statements
    for i := checkpoint; i < len(dbConfigs); i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(index int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            executeSQL(db, sql, &wg)
            // Update checkpoint after each migration
            if err := writeCheckpoint(index + 1); err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error writing checkpoint: %s", err)
            }
        }(i)
    }

    // Wait for all goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()

    // Remove checkpoint file upon successful completion
    if err := os.Remove(checkpointFilePath); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error removing checkpoint file: %s", err)
    }
}

Error:
$ go build main.go 
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:89:17: sql.Open undefined (type string has no field or method Open)

The command: go get -u github.com/lib/pq works fine for me.
I am running this on my macOS. What could be the issue?
I want to connect to the postgres db., and against each of the tenant, I want to run all the queries present in the sql file.
However, I am facing an issue in building the go package.

Unrelated to the problem: Please stop using filename arguments to go build.

The statement sql := string(sqlBytes) has "shadowed" the symbol sql which was a short name of an imported package database/sql, so to the compiler, an expression sql.Open was an attempt to call the method Open on a variable of type string; since that type does not have that method defined on it, the expression failed to compile.

[1/2] While we're at, I strongly suggest to make a habit of interpreting error messages literally: in this case, the compiler told you the exact reason: the type string has no field or method named Open, and the operator dot, ., is used in Go to access fields or methods of values, so clearly the compiler was sure the symbol sql to the left of the dot has type string. The natural next thing has to be tracing of all the occurences of that symbol in the source code (the search function of any text editor would do; IDEs could do much more).

[2/2] I mean, I'm reasonably long in the industry to herd newfangled devs and QAs and know that this is quite common a problem: a person sees an error and abruptly stops at that or–worse–invents their own interpretation of the cause w/o actually trying to make sense of the error's text and the context of its occurence. Of course, that may not be your case, but I think it's better to warn in vain that to not warn at all. To reiterate, interpret errors, do not just treat them as "something gone awry" opaque tokens.

You have
    sql := string(sqlBytes)

in line 75 (6th line of your main file). Usually your IDE should help you with this by navigating to the location of the definition:

